# Gradle build: does someone tried alternative build script with alternative setting.gradle?

Tags: build, command-line-arguments, gradle

I am using gradle 1.4, and renamed a build.gradle to buildExpr.gradle and settings.gradle to settingExpr.gradle, both files are in the project root, and I am using following command to run gradle build.

'gradle C:\myProject>gradle -i -b buildExpr.gradle -c settingsExpr.gradle project'

it seems command line option '-c' is not being honored and gradle is not picking settingsExpr.gradle file, hence it is not  able to display all modules defined in settings.gradle file while executing project task.

I am getting following log
-------------------------------------LOG----------------------------------------------------
C:\ASM\asm_workspace\asm71\AutoLab>gradle -i -c settingsExpr.gradle -b buildExpr.gradle project
Starting Build
**Settings evaluated using empty settings script.**
Projects loaded. Root project using build file 'C:\ASM\asm_workspace\asm71\AutoLab\buildExpr.gradle'.
Included projects: [root project 'AutoLab']
Evaluating root project 'AutoLab' using build file 'C:\ASM\asm_workspace\asm71\AutoLab\buildExpr.gradle'.
All projects evaluated.
Selected primary task 'projects'
Tasks to be executed: [task ':projects']
:projects

---

Root project

---

Root project 'AutoLab'
No sub-projects

---

it is very strange behavior by gradle command line shows. but if I change buildExpr.gradle to build.gradle and settingsExpr.gradle to settings.gradle, it executes normally and shows all sub-modules in log

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`-b` and `-c` can't be used together. When using a settings file, everything else (e.g. the locations of build files) is determined from the settings file.

Comment: so, if I am using command "C:\myProject>gradle -b buildExpr.gradle" is isn't suppose to pick default settings.gradle found in same folder. in my case it is not pick either.

Comment: No it isn't supposed to. `-b` and `settings.gradle` don't make much sense together because `settings.gradle` might nominate different/additional build scripts.

Comment: Then what do I need to do to include all modules defined in my settings.gradle if i want to build with anotherBuild.gradle?

Comment: You could pass a system property to the build (`-Dfoo=bar`) and configure different build scripts based on that (in `settings.gradle`). See `Settings` in the [Gradle Build Language Reference](http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/index.html). You could also apply different build scripts in your main build script (`apply from: "path/to/script.gradle"`) based on a system property. There might be other ways to tackle your bigger problem, but you'd have to explain what that is. If you need more advice, check out http://forums.gradle.org.

Comment: This is something that should be documented for the command-line options since this isn't an obvious behavior and the error is confusing. I made the same mistake (using -b and -c) and was wondering why my settings file was evaluated (it showed print statements) but not used ("Using empty settings").